# How can I resolve this constraint error when trying to load only data via pgloader?

Tags: postgresql, pgloader

I have the following .load file

```
LOAD DATABASE
     FROM      mysql://user:password@remotelocation/mydbname
     INTO postgresql://user@localhost/dbname

 WITH data only,truncate, workers = 8, concurrency = 1

  SET maintenance_work_mem to '128MB',
      work_mem to '12MB',
      search_path to 'mydbname'

 CAST type datetime to timestamptz drop default drop not null using zero-dates-to-null,
      type mediumint with extra auto_increment to bigserial,
      type date drop not null drop default using zero-dates-to-null,
      type tinyint to boolean using tinyint-to-boolean;
```

I get the error

```
Database error 2BP01: cannot drop constraint random_pkey on table random because other objects depend on it.
```

Can I load the data without dropping the key? I also have tried adding the `disable triggers` parameter to the with clause and that didn't work as well.

I am using postgre 9.6 and pgloader's version number is 3.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two items that fixed my issue. The first one being that the `include drop` parameter is turned on by default so I needed to add the `include no drop` parameter and secondly some bugs were recently fixed in this area so I also needed to compile pgloader from source.